# How to add a column based on condition in python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes where i want to append two columns based on a condition.

I have the two following dataframes:

[image: Data 1]

[image: Data 2]

I want to add TS%_mean and TS%_SD to the other data if the year matches to the first DataFrame so that each player has their mean and standard deviation for that year.

I have tried to iterate over a loop and having some conditions for the addition of columns. Everything I have tried does not work as intended unfortunately.

Comment: have you tried merge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `df` and `df2`, you can use `merge`.

```
df.merge(df2, on = 'Year')
```

You may also want to study [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Although the link is SQL-based, you will learn the basics of joining tables in order to create more complex joins.